# Serving Angular index.html page - server rendered or static

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I see in every yeoman generator for the meanjs stack that they all have a server side rendered index.html page.  Primarily, this is adding/removing  environment specific conditional statements that will send the rendered page to the client for which environment you have deployed to.  I am wondering would it be better to just compile the swig/jade/ejs template in a grunt/gulp task prior to deployment then serve it up statically with the application rather than spend server resources in compiling it on every request?  The latter option would allow you to host your angular application on a CDN as well.

Comment: Express does cache your views on production environments. http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.render